# Enable visitors to share large image from website to their Facebook wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

How do I enable visitors on my website to like/share an image on my site and have a large image appear on their wall ... the same size as if they were to like/share a wall photo (300px wide) ... instead of the thumbnail (90px wide).

I can get the thumbnail size to appear using the basic like/share button, but I want the larger wall-size photo to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the current plugins.  You should file a bug with Facebook at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs so it can be added to the wishlist.

Comment: Thanks - no one I've talked to has been able to figure this out.  Submitting a bug report is a great tip.